# Thread locks simulating an intersection

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am trying to simulate an intersection using threads and mutex locks.

I have functions for going strait, turn left, turn right.
Now, i have a function for approaching the intersection. This generates a random orientation and turn. Each thread shares the approaching intersection.

I have all the locks defined for all the cars in all directions.

Take the going strait function. It has a switch statement that just prints what car is doing what at the time. Now, i am just not sure what to lock in this function. If the car is in direction pointing north would i lock east and west and same with the car pointing south going north?

Here is my locks which just calls a function to lock or unlock

```
#define NUMCARS 30

#define lock_NW(CAR) lock(CAR, NW_mutex)
#define lock_NE(CAR) lock(CAR, NE_mutex)
#define lock_SW(CAR) lock(CAR, SW_mutex)
#define lock_SE(CAR) lock(CAR, SE_mutex)

#define unlock_NW(CAR) unlock(CAR, NW_mutex)
#define unlock_NE(CAR) unlock(CAR, NE_mutex)
#define unlock_SW(CAR) unlock(CAR, SW_mutex)
#define unlock_SE(CAR) unlock(CAR, SE_mutex)
```

here is main

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
/* Initial variables*/
int index, tid;
unsigned int carids[NUMCARS];
pthread_t carthreads[NUMCARS];

/* Start up a thread for each car*/ 
for(index = 0; index <NUMCARS; index++){
carids[index] = index;
tid = pthread_create(&carthreads[index], NULL, approachintersection,  (void*)&carids[index]);
}

/* Wait for every car thread to finish */
for(index = 0; index <NUMCARS; index++){
pthread_join(carthreads[index], NULL);
}
printf("Done\n");
return 1;
}
```

here is the approaching intersection which calls the function going strait

```
static void * approachintersection(void* arg){
unsigned int * carnumberptr;
unsigned int carnumber;
orientation_t cardir = (orientation_t)random()%4;
unsigned long turn = random()%3;

carnumberptr = (unsigned int*) arg;
carnumber = (unsigned int) *carnumberptr;

if(turn==LEFT){
turnleft(cardir, carnumber);
} else if(turn==RIGHT){
turnright(cardir, carnumber);
} else {//straight
gostraight(cardir, carnumber);
}

return (void*)carnumberptr;
}
```

Now, here is the going strait function where i want to lock the appropriate directions.

```
 /*
  cardirection - The direction the car is pointing.  If it is pointing NORTH,
  it is starting from the South-Eastern corner of the intersection
  and "going straight" means it wants to move SOUTH to NORTH.

  valid options: NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST

 carnumber -    The car identifier
*/


static void gostraight(orientation_t cardirection, unsigned int carnumber){

switch(cardirection){
case NORTH:
printf("Car %d, Moving South-North\n", carnumber);
break;
case SOUTH:
printf("Car %d, Moving North-South\n", carnumber);
break;
case EAST:
printf("Car %d, Moving West-East\n", carnumber);
break;
case WEST:
printf("Car %d, Moving East-West\n", carnumber);
break;
}
}
```

So, if the approaching car is pointing north from south the car would be the SE car and i would lock case east, west print function with lock_SE(CAR)? preventing the other threads from coming in and printing? so i would lock unlock the print statements?

Or would i lock the whole switch statement?

** EDIT:  would this be the way to do it? **

```
static void turnleft(orientation_t cardirection, unsigned int carnumber){

int CAR;
CAR = carnumber;


  switch(cardirection){
  case NORTH:
  lock_SE(CAR)
  printf("Car %d, Moving South-West\n", carnumber);
  unlock_SE(CAR)
  break;
  case SOUTH:
  lock_NW(CAR)
  printf("Car %d, Moving North-East\n", carnumber);
  unlock_NW(CAR)
  break;
  case EAST:
  lock_SW(CAR)
  printf("Car %d, Moving West-North\n", carnumber);
  unlock_SW(CAR)
  break;
  case WEST:
  lock_NE(CAR)
  printf("Car %d, Moving East-South\n", carnumber);
  unlock_NE(CAR)
  break;
  }
```

}

Comment: A coarse-grained approach would lock the entire intersection (switch statement), meaning only one car could enter the intersection from any direction at a time. You probably want a more fine-grained approach, where each car locks one or more quadrants of the intersection (right turn - one, straight - two, left turn - three - in a consistent order to prevent deadlocks).

Comment: So, if the switch case is NORTH inside that switch would i lock the other directions and then after the print unlock those? Would i do that for every switch case?

Comment: I just dont know how to do this. Can you give me one example without deadlocks?

Comment: If you decide any order on locks (1st, 2nd etc.) and always access them in that order you can not have deadlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an easy problem. I'll try to show two solutions.

First the obvious one: One mutex for the entire intersection, in the beginning of `turnleft, turnright, gostraight` add `lock(car, intersection_mutex);`, just before the end of each function release said mutex. This will only let one car in through the intersection at a time. The upside of this is that it's easy to understand and will not result in dead locks. The downside is that a only one car can enter at a time but as we all know two cars travelling non-intersecting paths can enter without issues. 
Here's an example of `go_straight()` (the others follow the same approach):

```
static void gostraight(orientation_t cardirection, unsigned int carnumber){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&intersection_mutex);
    switch(cardirection){
        case NORTH:
            printf("Car %d, Moving South-North\n", carnumber);
            break;
        case SOUTH:
            printf("Car %d, Moving North-South\n", carnumber);
            break;
        case EAST:
            printf("Car %d, Moving West-East\n", carnumber);
            break;
        case WEST:
            printf("Car %d, Moving East-West\n", carnumber);
            break;
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&intersection_mutex);
}
```

To let more than one car in at a time we need a fine grained approach. The problem with a fine grained approach is that it's much harder to implement and get correct. Both `go_straight` and `turn_left` needs to lock two mutexes (you could argue that turn left needs three..). So if you can't acquire both mutexes you need to back off. Translating this into driving rules:

```
you must not enter the intersection before you can exit it.
```

So, to go straight we must first acquire the mutex nearest to you, then the next one in your path to be able to exit. If we can't get both we must release the one we have locked. If we don't release it we will dead-lock.

To do this I'd add two helper functions:

```
static void lock_two(pthread_mutex_t *a, pthread_mutex_t *b) {
    while(1) { 
        pthread_mutex_lock(a);
        if(pthread_mutex_trylock(b) == 0) 
            break;
        else
        /* We must release the previously taken mutex so we don't dead lock the intersection */
            pthread_mutex_unlock(a);                            
        pthread_yield(); /* so we don't spin over lock/try-lock failed */
    }
}
static void unlock_two(pthread_mutex_t *a, pthread_mutex_t *b) {
    pthread_mutex_unlock(a);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(b);
}
```

Here's my version of go straight:

```
static void gostraight(orientation_t cardirection, unsigned int carnumber){  
    switch(cardirection){
        case NORTH:
            lock_two(&SE_mutex, &NE_mutex); 
            printf("Car %d, Moving South-North\n", carnumber);
            unlock_two(&SE_mutex, &NE_mutex); 
            break;
        case SOUTH:
            lock_two(&NW_mutex, &SW_mutex); 
            printf("Car %d, Moving North-South\n", carnumber);
            unlock_two(&NW_mutex, &SW_mutex); 
            break;
        case EAST:
            lock_two(&SW_mutex, &SE_mutex); 
            printf("Car %d, Moving West-East\n", carnumber);
            unlock_two(&SW_mutex, &SE_mutex); 
       break;
       case WEST:
            lock_two(&NE_mutex, &NW_mutex); 
            printf("Car %d, Moving East-West\n", carnumber);
            unlock_two(&NE_mutex, &NW_mutex); 
            break;
    }
}
```

`turn_left` would then need to follow the same approach.

Comment: This just validates what i thought i needed to do. Thank you for responding.

Comment: in going straight function: If we are going south to north shouldn't we also lock SW car from going west to east?

Comment: Does it matter how i unlock because this scheme is producing deadlocks.

Comment: Are you using my lock_two method? It will lock two mutexes. I'm not sure I understand your question? If you are going North (and I assume right hand traffic) you only need to lock SE and NE. When you hold both the car going east will try to lock both SW and SE, and since it can't lock both won't enter the intersection.

Comment: Well i am doing exactly what you said but the program is not exiting properly. Just hangs. Only a few cars are working. There is suppose to be 30 cars but im only getting maybe 10 sometimes more.

Comment: I am only lockig the quadrants that the car will be currently using. So if car 1 is pointing north he locks SE, NE, and NW

Comment: i think the problem lies in the turn functions. I commented out all the locks in go strait and it deadlocks still

Comment: I know its in my turn right function. Do i just lock once? So if im pointing north and in SE i just lock SE?

Comment: Yes, when i do any type of locking in the turn right function it produces dead locks. If i dont have any locks in there it exits perfectly. What could be wrong?

Comment: Yes I'd only lock one quadrant for the right hand turn. I assumed you only needed two locks for the left hand turn (I'd say this depends). Are you using pthread mutextes (I assumed you did)?

Comment: Im using 3 locks for the left hand turn - case NORTH:
   lock_SE(CAR)
   lock_NE(CAR)
   lock_NW(CAR)

Comment: @Gille: I seem to have a problem to understand that you can do this with only four mutexes. IMHO, if you have four cars, one south going east, one east going south, one north going west and one west going north, all four cars could pass the intersection at the same time. But the way you lock up to three of four mutexes (e.g. for going left), the intersection would not allow my scenario, right? I know that it works correctly, but it would block more than necessary IMHO.

Comment: what two locks do i need for a left hand turn? It appears to me it should be 3. Say pointing NORTH - wouldn't i need to lock lock_SE(CAR),lock_NE(CAR), and lock_NW(CAR)?

Answer (score 1):

Well something like this would work for the going straight function :-

```
static void gostraight(orientation_t cardirection, unsigned int carnumber){
  int CAR;
  cAR = carnumber;

  switch(cardirection){
    case NORTH:
      lock_SE(CAR);
      lock_NE(CAR);
      printf("Car %d, Moving South-North\n", carnumber);
      unlock_NE(CAR);
      unlock_SE(CAR);
      break;
    case SOUTH:
      lock_NW(CAR);
      lock_SW(CAR);
      printf("Car %d, Moving North-South\n", carnumber);
      unlock_SW(CAR);
      unlock_NW(CAR);
      break;
    case EAST:
      lock_SE(CAR);
      lock_SW(CAR);
      printf("Car %d, Moving West-East\n", carnumber);
      unlock_SE(CAR);
      unlock_SW(CAR);
      break;
    case WEST:
      lock_NE(CAR);
      lock_NW(CAR);
      printf("Car %d, Moving East-West\n", carnumber);
      unlock_NW(CAR);
      unlock_NE(CAR);
      break;
  }
}
```

For the left turn, (just giving one example) :-

```
switch(cardirection) {
  case NORTH:
    lock_SE(CAR);
    lock_NE(CAR);
    lock_NW(CAR);
    printf("Car %d, Moving South-West\n", carnumber);
    unlock_NW(CAR);
    unlock_NE(CAR);
    unlock_SE(CAR);
    break;
}
```

For right turn (again just one example) :-

```
switch(cardirection) {
  case EAST:
    lock_SW(CAR);
    printf("Car %d, Moving East-South\n", carnumber);
    unlock_SW(CAR);
    break;
}
```

Note that in order to avoid deadlocks, I am always locking them in the arbitrary order of SE, NE, NW, SW.

Why this works? e.g., take a car that wants to go straight south and another that is headed north and turning left to west. 
Then if the left turning car comes first, it will lock SE, NE and NW in that order and the straight going car will not be able to get the lock on NW. However, a car going east and turning right to south will be able to get the lock on SW.

Hence, this scheme will work. It won't have a deadlock because each function obtains the locks in a given order. Hence there can never be cyclic chain of threads competing for corners. Basically, if a thread 1 is waiting for a thread 2 to release a lock, then that means thread 2 does not require any of the locks already obtained by thread 1. Hence there can be no deadlock.

Comment: This will dead lock if you have multiple cars all going straight. You must unlock the first mutex if you can't obtain the second immediately. Assume car 1 going north, takes SE, car 2 going south takes NW, car 3 going west takes NE, car 4 going east takes SE. Now back to car 1, he tries to take NE but it's already taken and won't be freed until car 4 can take NW, which won't be freed.. etc. look at my answer how to solve this.

Comment: aha but car 4 going east can't take SE because car 1 has already taken it! Hence it won't deadlock.

Comment: Basically I have enforced that if car 1 is waiting for car 2 then by virtue of the order in which the locks are taken, car 2 cannot require a lock that car 1 has already taken! Hence, there can never be a cyclic chain of resource locks.

Comment: Does it matter how i unlock because this scheme is producing deadlocks.

Comment: no it doesn't. and this shouldn't produce deadlocks. can you give the specific example of dependency chain?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you need to do, but I'll have a try at explaining my reasoning. I'll start at the design, since I guess that's where your problem lies.

You assume a plain intersection, two roads, no lights, no signs. Any car can arrive at the intersection from four different directions, north, south, east and west, and each car can take one of three different directions when passing the intersection.
This way, you have `4 * 3 = 12` different road sections you'd have to consider, all different.

If a car crosses the intersection on a certain path at a certain moment, it blocks traffic at zero or more, theoretically up to 11, different sections (in practice, at least two sections remain free, so the limit is 9). These you have to block. BTW, it helps if you make a picture of the 12 different sections.

If you want to use mutexes, you'd need one for each section (not necessarily for a car). Assuming a right hand, right-before-left driving scenario, a car coming from the south intending to go straight would be blocking:

- a car coming from the east going straight;
- a car coming from the east going left;
- a car coming from the east going right;
- a car coming from the west going straight;
- a car coming from the west going left;
- a car coming from the north going left;

All other sections are free for other cars. You can create this list of blocks for every arrival/direction pair. [You'd have to specify how two left-turning cars from opposite directions shall pass each other, i.e. whether a car coming from north turning left will block a car coming from south turning left, or whether they can pass before one another]

Blocking so many mutexes (one for each section) on behalf of each car (read: thread) presents a problem: Deadlock. In order to solve that problem here, I'd suggest you create an additional, 'master' mutex for the whole intersection.
When a car arrives,

1. it tries to block the master mutex; if unsuccessful, it blocks.
2. it then tries to block each of the section-mutexes it needs; if unsuccessful, release all successfully locked mutexes, unlock the master mutex, and wait, then try again starting from 1.
3. If it succeeded in blocking all needed section mutexes, unlock the master mutex, and pass the intersection (taking time).

After passing the intersection, the car

1. tries to block the master mutex; if unsuccessful, it blocks.
2. it unlocks all acquired section mutexes.
3. it unlocks the master mutex again.
4. continues its way in the new direction.

[Edited to clarify, and pthread mutexes allow trying to lock and backing off]
The master mutex is always released very quickly, only used to see if a car can obtain all necessary section mutexes or not. Either way, the master mutex is released immediately aftre that.

Without a master mutex you can avoid deadlock only by using a strict order for obtaining the mutexes. This would make the intersection partial: If two cars arrive at the same time, one direction/turn combination will always win over another one. The master mutex avoids that.